# i have a list than contain more dict in it and want delete one of them but the dict are dynamics

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

so i have a list and in it i have some dict,i have a function where ask with 2 input which dict add,
then i have an other function with 1 input for  which dict remove, is possibile do that?

```
my_list = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]

def add_dict():
    my_dict = {}
    add_key = input("insert key : ")
    add_value = input("insert value: ")
    my_dict[add_key] = add_value
    return my_list.append(my_dict)
```

if i add something like {"e":"f"} become

```
my_list = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]
```

i need a function that remove a dict like {"c":"d"}

```
def remove_dict():
  delete = input("with dict want remove? ")
```

where the result should be

```
my_list = [{"a":"b"},{"e":"f"}]
```

Comment: Why a list of dictionaries instead of just a dictionary? You can do `del yourdict[key]` then.

Comment: Do you want to remove any dictionnary that has a `"c"` key? Or one with specifically the `"c:" "d"` key-value pair?

Comment: @Guimoute that specifically dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you would just be looking to delete the value by specifying the key of the dictionary you could do the following:

```
def remove_dict():
    delete_value = str(input("with dict want remove? "))
    for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
        if list(my_list[i].keys()) == [delete_value]:
            del my_list[i]
```

just specify the letter upon request and it should delete the value from your list of dictionaries.

for example:

```
my_list = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]
my_list
[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}]

remove_dict()
with dict want remove? c

my_list
[{'a': 'b'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

just a note: the way it's set up you wouldn't need to use quotes (' ') in your input.

if you want to specify the whole dictionary value (i.e. {"c":"d"}) then this would work:

```
def remove_dict():
delete_value = input("with dict want remove? ")
for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
    if str(my_list[i]) == delete_value:
        del my_list[i]
```

then you would get:

```
remove_dict()
with dict want remove? {'c': 'd'}

my_list
[{'a': 'b'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

Comment: that  was what i looking for

Comment: Great to hear! let me know if you still have questions

Comment: Please don't forget to confirm the correct answer so people with the same question can refer to it. @GiulioZorzi

Comment: Why bother with extra lists and indexes `for i in range(len(my_list)-1): if list(my_list[i].keys()) == [delete_value]: del my_list[i]`? Just do `for a_dict in my_list_of_dicts: if delete_value in a_dict.keys(): del a_dict`.

Comment: @Guimoute Hi, he specified in his comments that he wasn't interested in deleting the item based on the key, but the actual key+value combination

Comment: Yes, but you still want to iterate over the objects themselves and not a range.

Comment: this allows more flexibility as to what item you want to call with the for statement. We are not particularly optimizing for speed here and since the input type, the actual list item type and the key type are all different types it is nice to have this added flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

you can just iterate through the list of dicts and check if the item you want to delete is a key in each dict.

```py
my_list = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"}]
delete = input("with dict want remove? ")
for index, dic in enumerate(my_list):
    if delete in dic:
        del my_list[index]
print(my_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
with dict want remove? c
[{'a': 'b'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like for your use case to store your input data in a dict it is more suitable rather than in a list:

```
my_dict = {"a":"b", "c":"d"}

def add_dict():
    add_key = input("insert key : ")
    add_value = input("insert value: ")
    my_dict[add_key] = add_value
```

and to remove:

```
def remove_dict():
    key = input("with dict want remove? ")
    my_dict.pop(key) # you may want to check if the key is in the dict
```